# Can't boot latests Lives for install without kernel option "noapic", would like support to debug

Tags: boot, kernel

I Hope you're doing fine!
I am Mickaël.

First post without completely reading recommendations about posting, so sorry in advance if something is not the way it should.

Here is my issue : I have this machine live booted with `noapic` at kernel boot, works fine :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg -T | tee /tmp/info.log ; sudo lspci -vvv | tee -a /tmp/info.log ; sudo dmidecode | tee -a /tmp/info.log
```

https://pastebin.com/mr25jMUd
Added Kernel freez here :
https://pastebin.com/6hnBp0un

I would like to "try" to debug the kernel issue which just hang forever without `noapic` at kernel boot at :
`DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 6 under DRHD base  0xfbffe000 IOMMU 1`

Thanks for any recommendations.
Have a nice day,
Mickaël.

Comment: The first thing to check is that all your firmware on motherboard and ssd is up-to-date.  Check with the vendors regularly.

Comment: Hello ubfan1, thanks for your recommendations, but this hardware is not supported anymore, so impossible to do that, already latest. Everything else work correctly W|XP/7/8/10 | *BSD, ects... Does not boot after kernel around 4.4. Have a nice day!